# Функции (метрики) для оценки качества классификации

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Как с помощью `sklearn` или `numpy` найти долю ошибочно предсказанных значений?

Есть два массива чисел одной длины `a, b`, где `a` - настоящие значения, а `b` - предсказанные. Надо сравнить их, а количество неправильных ответов поделить на длину. Можно это как-то сделать в 1 функцию?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise

Comment: Какая у вас модель- регрессия или классификация? Для разных типов используют разные метрики

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics - функции-метрики

Comment: @MaxU классификация

Comment: @Victor сравнить, потом посчитать количество неправильных, а потом разделить я тоже могу. Меня интересует, есть ли специальные функции для этого

Comment: @MaxU какая функция выдаёт нужное значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для оценки качества классификации обычно используют одну или несколько [метрик для задач классификации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics):

- `accuracy_score` - Accuracy classification score
- `auc` - AUC (Area Under Curve)
- `average_precision_score` - Compute average precision (AP) from prediction scores
- ...

Выбор метрики может сильно зависеть от задачи и от качества данных.

**Пример:**
пусть у нас есть задача бинарной классификации - определить является ли финансовая транзакция мошенничеством или нет. В обучающей выборке присутствует 1.5% транзакций от общего числа, размеченных как мошенничество. Если мы построим модель которая будет отмечать **все** транзакции как хорошие (не мошенничество), то точность предсказания, используя метрику `accuracy` - будет 98.5%. Т.е. число 98.5% в данном случае ничего не скажет нам о качестве модели в случае сильно разбалансированных данных. Именно поэтому существует множество различных метрик, чтобы можно было оценивать модели по разным характеристикам.

Comment: `1 - accuracy_score` с параметром `Normalize=True` решает мою задачу короче